# Cannot Sign Up for Alerts Because "You Have No Email Address"

Tags: alert

When I create a new account in Active Directory, then sign in to Sharepoint (2010) with that account, and then try to sign up for alerts, I can, indeed sign up for alerts, but I get an error message saying:

> You do not have an email address

Now, the address *IS* there in Active Directory, and I can see it in MySites, too.  It is in the right field as well.

I tried running the timer jobs, but it still doesn't work.
How can I get it to take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have User Profile up and running?? If so, follow this procedure http://yagyashree.wordpress.com/set-up-alerts-for-contacts-in-active-directory-in-the-sharepoint-site/

Make sure you run Full User Profile Syncronization via Central admin > Monitoring -> Review job definitions -> "User Profile Service Application - User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization"

Comment: Marius is right on this, it looks like the local data isn't synced yet or at all. You perhaps should also check the hidden list (Enter tobias) http://zimmergren.net/technical/sharepoints-hidden-user-list-user-information-list to see if that is being updated also.

Comment: Mr. Marius, my full user profile syn was set to run hourly.  I waited on it, and even ran a batch command to run all the timer jobs.  But it seems to have run *sometime* and the email alert works now.

Comment: Mr. Wood - thanks for that "hidden" item.  I added it to the Sharepoint Administrator's Toolbar: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/SPAdminToolbar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue this steps solved my issue

http://ittechnotebook.blogspot.com/2014/10/cannot-sign-up-for-alerts-because-you.html

Comment: Please add a summary of the steps outlined in that blog post to your answer. Link-only answers tend to lose their usefulness over time as links have a tendency to break.

Comment: This site is not for promoting your own blog posts. Please add more details to your answers now and in the future!